# Convert huge (10-100MB of plain text) Mathematica function for external use

Tags: compile, fortran

I have a huge Mathematica function (plain text ranging 10-100MB) that I am trying to convert to Fortran for external use. I tried using FortranForm, which does most of the work, and cleaned the code by hand using vim and some replacements.

When I try to evaluate the function, I get a Nan.
Here's the problem: given the sheer size of the function, the compile-time already takes a long time and I can't seem to be able to compile with debugging flags to see where the Nan originates.
My apologies for the vagueness of the question, but all input is welcome.
I also tried using MathCodeF90 but it seems to be too slow to generate that huge amount of code.

Comment: So you have a single `Function` that is 100MB large? Is it partially data and partially code? Or is it 100MB of pure WL code?

Comment: It is only code, think a really long and ugly combination of simple functions... mostly exponentials, complex conjugation, trigonometric functions and polynomials.

Comment: The function was created in Mathematica, nobody could write that much text. There's no way around that. My problem is quite a technical one, on how to approach the problem...

Comment: Is there any way the code generator could be simplified? Speaking generally and imprecisely, in any algorithm, a certain amount of it is data/memory/state, and a certain amount is code/instructions/time - it's always a trade-off. I find it hard to imagine what sort of physical problem needs 100MB of executable code that couldn't be instead 5MB code, 95MB data that the code uses. I'm guessing but 100MB of code will likely miss cache a lot too and give poor performance. If it's a very big expression generated by some formal process, it would make sense to code that in C or Fortran instead.

Comment: I don't see any way the code can be obtained directly in c or Fortran. The expression was generated with mathematica, it is the result of analytical calculations, and from what I can tell it can't be simplified anymore. I have a couple expressions. But the problem is there, even for a smaller expression of a few MB, which is already a lot.

Comment: Perhaps you could give us a sample of what generates the long expression? Is it a differential equation, integral, nested function etc.?

Comment: Hard to say anything without the code that generates the code, but it sounds as if you really do not want to compute analytic expressions in the first place. Analytic expressions tend to blow up super-linearly by even the simplest algebraic operations (e.g. the product of two matrices). Instead, you should try to chop the action of that expression on the input in smaller manageable (or even repeatedly usable) pieces, and implement them efficiently for floating point numbers of your desired precision. This may take several human days, and probably nobody else but you can do it...

Comment: That said, it is very likely that the actual amount of number crunching that you needs is orders of magnitude smaller than logic required by the CPU to "understand" you 100MB function.

Comment: You could try to generate abbreviations for common subexpressions automatically, e.g., by Write2 from FenCalc  (http://www.feyncalc.org/FeynCalcBook/Write2/)

Comment: This might do the trick? https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/690/ Try for instance `IPX[Integrate[1/(y - x^10), x], x, s]`

Comment: If one did manage successfully translate the MMA output into a correct Fortran input I'd expect most compilers to choke on it.  I'd have thunk that the 'right' solution is to decompose the mega-(actually multi-mega-) function on the MMA side as @HenrikSchumacher has already suggested.

Comment: Assuming that you need the 100MB-long function, then it sounds like you are requesting a means of debugging it to find out why it is giving NaN. This sounds like you'll need to be able to break out the subexpressions of the expression-tree and evaluate them separately until you find the offending subexpression. (But I wonder if you ever do fix your equation and get out some number how you will have any confidence in it being correct, given its complexity?)

Comment: You all make good points. I'll probably try to break down the expression. I had tried with a shorter one (still long by human standards) and it was working. So I guess I am confident that the evaluation is correct when the Mathematica and Fortran evaluations of the function agree.

Comment: I also tried another way. Have a Mathematica script that is called by the code through a system call. But that, in the current form I have, is really slow, because every time the script is called there's the whole Mathematica overhead. Is there a way to keep the Mathematica kernel running, with the function already loaded, that can be called again and again through a system call in Fortran to evaluate the function? (Hope this makes sense)